# Удалить строчку через регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
bbbbb
aaaa

aaaa
bbbbbbb

bbbbbbbb
aaaa

aaaa
bbbbbbbbb
и т.д.
```

В этом коде нужно удалить все строчки aaaa, после которых идет новая пустая строчка. А строчку aaaa после которой идет bbbb при этом оставить. Пробую через регулярные выражение в Notepad++: - aaaa$ удаляет обе строчки. aaaa$\r - вообще не находит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, выражение, чтобы удалялась только первая строчка. Выражение, насколько понимаю должно быть такого вида: aaaa[конец строки][новая строка]

Comment: Регулярные выражения такими вопросами, как номера строк не занимаются. В какой программе вы пытаетесь использовать выражения ? Делайте это другими средствами языка

Comment: в npp это можно сделать следующим образом: ищем `^aaaa(.*)`, заменяем на `$1`, только не забываем поставить галочку "и новые строки", иначе сработает не как надо

Comment: я только что использовал эту регулярку и сделал нормальную замену. Т.е. если работает не как надо, значит вы не правильно поставили задачу. Приведите пример, когда мое решение не работает. И вы не забыли поставить галочку "и новые строки"? Без нее работать как надо не будет

Comment: а обновить нельзя? сейчас 6.8.8 актуальная (я проверял на 6.6.9), либо поставить [sublime text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), 5ой у меня нет, поэтому посмотреть не могу

Comment: `(.*?)\r\n^aaaa$(.*)` вроде удаляет то, что нужно, только заменять надо на `$1$2`, не забываем про "новые строки"

Comment: а сколько раз должна? вы же сами написали: *чтобы удалялась только первая строчка*, она и удаляет только первую строчку (т.е. один раз), что не так?

Answer (score 1):

`^aaaa[\r\n|\r|\n]{2}` - ищет aaaa с начала строки + два переноса на новую строку

**Upd:** поправил в связи с уточнением вопроса

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35782/discussion-on-answer-by-ruslank-----).

Answer (score 1):

Найдены рабочие варианты:

```
^aaaa\r\n\r\n
^aaaa(\r\n|\r|\n)^$
^aaaa(\r\n|\r|\n)\1
```

Спасибо @BOPOH и @RuslanK